# How to JQuery validators to HTML form input element?

Tags: jquery, validation, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-form

currently, I am adding it in script on form submit

```
$("#formname").validate({ 
  //Rules ex
  rules:{
   nameoffield :{
    specialChar: true,
    email:true
                }
        }
 });
```

Can we add it in line? like

```
    <form:input name="nameoffield" path="" **specialChar** **email**/>
```

I want to move all the rules into a common JSP, include that JSP everywhere and just add the rules inline.
TIA

Comment: Html `inputs` provides various `attributes` to achieve above. Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes).

Comment: @Swati
I saw them, not able to find any, where I can use custom jquery rules like.

  **$.validator.addMethod("somePattern", function(value, element) {
         if (condition) {
           return false;     
         }else{
           return true;
         }
     });**